# replacing attributes within an html image tag

Tags: vb.net, html-agility-pack

I have a 1000+ database entries that contain html image tags.

The problem is, 90% of the 'src' attributes are just placeholders.  I need to replace all of those placeholders with the appropriate, real sources.

A typical database entry looks like this(the amount of image tags vary from entry to entry):

```
<p>A monster rushes at you!</p>
Monster:<p><img id="d8fh4-gfkj3" src="(image_placeholder)" /></p>
<br />
Treasure: <p><img id="x23zo-115a9" src="(image_placeholder)" /></p>
Please select your action below:
</br />
```

Using the IDs in the image tags above, 'd8fh4-gfkj3' & 'x23zo-115a9', I can query another function to get the "real" sources for those images.

So I tried using HtmlAgilityPack and came up with this(below):

```
    Dim doc As New HtmlDocument()
    doc.LoadHtml(encounterText)

    For Each imgTag As HtmlNode In doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img")
        'get the ID
        Dim imgId As HtmlAttribute = imgTag.Attributes("id")
        Dim imageId As String = imgId.Value

        'get the new/real path
        Dim newPath = getMediaPath(imageId)
        Dim imgSrc As HtmlAttribute = imgTag.Attributes("src")

        'check to see if the <img> tag "src" attribute has a placeholder
        If imgSrc.Value.Contains("(image_placeholder)") Then
            'replace old image src attribute with 'src=newPath'
        End If
    Next
```

But I can't figure out how to actually replace the old value with the new value.

Is there a way to do this with the HtmlAgilityPack?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just set the value for the attribute:

```
'check to see if the <img> tag "src" attribute has a placeholder
If imgSrc.Value.Contains("(image_placeholder)") Then
    'replace old image src attribute with 'src=newPath'
    imgSrc.Value = newPath
End If
```

After the replacement, you can get the updated HTML with:

```
doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml
```